# Trying to copy "0.75" as a double from argv[]

Tags: c, double, argv

For some reason anything I try results in numbers after the decimal place being disregarded.

`sscanf(argv[5], "%.2lf", &add4);` doesn't work

`add4 = atof(argv[5]);` doesn't work

Any help?
1: program name (aka for the program im trying to solve currently, i need the following parameters. of these, double isnt getting saved properly)
2: string
3: int
4: int
5: double

all but the double are being copied into my arrays fine. I've tried the above two ways of copying the double but both result in numbers after the decimal being .00

Declarations:
`char add1[50];
int add2, add3;
double add4;`

This call adds a new line to a list .csv file:

`inv add banana 2 2 2.50`

where below, `command` has already been assigned the string "add".

what would end up listed would be:

"banana, 2, 2, 2.00" at the end of my text file

```
if(strcmp(command,"add") == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(add1, argv[2]);
                    add2 = atoi(argv[3]);
                    add3 = atoi(argv[4]);
                    add4 = atof(argv[5]);

                    FILE *fp3 = fopen("replica.csv", "w");
                    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                    {
                        fprintf (fp3, "%s,%d,%d,%.2lf\n", item[j], quantity[j], limit[j], cost[j]);
                    }   

                    fprintf(fp3, "%s,%d,%d,%.2lf\n", add1, add2, add3, add4);

                    fclose(fp1);
                    fclose(fp3);
                    remove("inventory.csv");
                    rename("replica.csv", "inventory.csv"); 
                }
```

Comment: can you add more code and an example of call with command line args?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "doesn't work" part? Perhaps edit your question to include a more complete example (preferably a so-called [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))? And you *have* at least five command line arguments, with the fifth being the number? Please edit your question to show how you invoke your program as well.

Comment: Are you saying that you have *four* command line arguments, and want to get the value from the *fifth*? Remember that the indexes for `argv` are `1` for the first argument, `2` for the second, etc.

Comment: my bad, the first is actually the name of the program i want to run, while the argv[]s onward are just parameters id need for that program

Comment: Please show the *complete* and *actual* command line, and a *complete* code example.

Comment: On which platform are you (e.g. Windows, Linux OSX)? What terminal program are you using? Because unless you have a space before or after the decimal point in the number, then it seems the terminal program cuts your command line at the decimap point.

Comment: Show declaration (and allocation) of `add4`

Comment: im using command prompt with windows 7, and no spaces

Comment: One thing you can try, print the value of `argv[5]`, like `printf("argv[5] = '%s'\n", argv[5]);`. Then you can see exactly what is passed to you. Also print `argc` to see how many arguments are passed to you, if it's not `6` when you pass five arguments, there's something wrong.

Comment: for some odd reason nothing gets printed. it seems like printf isnt working at all

Comment: You didn't forget the newline? Also, please show the declarations of the `addX` variables, especially `add1`.

Comment: wow, i just made the dumbest mistake of all time. there is no problem anymore. >.<

Comment: Care to elaborate? What was the mistake? Could it be something that other can learn from?

Comment: it was due to running my executable which i had changed to a different name, instead of the actual saved file..

Answer (score 1):

Enable more warnings and check the return value of `sscanf`.

```
% clang test.c
test.c:5:28: warning: invalid conversion specifier '.' [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
        int n = sscanf(argv[1], "%.2lf", &x);
                                 ~^
1 warning generated.
```

`atof` works for me. Make sure you're including stdlib. You could also try `stdtod(argv[5], NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sscanf(argv[5], "%lf", &add4);
```

Comment: doesnt work, still 0s after decimal

Comment: Then the issue is not with the sscanf, but with the printf().  Try printf("%3.2lf\n", add4);

Comment: printf isnt working at all for some reason

Comment: SORRY EVERYONE... DUMB MISTAKE ON MY PART..